# LibGdx, viewport/camera#unproject sometimes (not always) returns wrong values

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx, 2d

I use OrthographicCamera and unproject function to convert screen point to world point.

Everything works fine, but sometimes #unproject method returns some almost good/expected value, but almost, so you see it as screen/world jumps X pixels/units around.

```
//screenX, screenY -> mouse position when wheel is scrolled

(...) <- calculate new world size because of zooming and set it up in viewport object

//calculate difference in world two points
//where mouse was before zooming and where mouse is after it,
//related to worldCoords, and apply it to camera:
Vector2 before = viewport.unproject(new Vector2(screenX, screenY));
camera.viewportWidth = viewport.getWorldWidth();
camera.viewportHeight = viewport.getWorldHeight();
camera.update();
Vector2 after = viewport.unproject(new Vector2(screenX, screenY));
camera.position.x -= after.x - before.x;
camera.position.y -= after.y - before.y;
```

This code just adds focusing on "point in world" feature - to zooming

EDIT / Solution? :

The method update in OrthographicCamera class:

```
@Override
    public void update (boolean updateFrustum) {
        projection.setToOrtho(zoom * -viewportWidth / 2, zoom * (viewportWidth / 2), zoom * -(viewportHeight / 2), zoom
            * viewportHeight / 2, near, far);
        view.setToLookAt(position, tmp.set(position).add(direction), up);
        combined.set(projection);
        Matrix4.mul(combined.val, view.val);

        if (updateFrustum) {
            invProjectionView.set(combined);
            Matrix4.inv(invProjectionView.val);
            frustum.update(invProjectionView);
        }
    }
```

It looks like this line is guilty:

```
view.setToLookAt(position, tmp.set(position).add(direction), up);
```

You can copy code of this method and create your own, without it. I guess this method is just little buggy and it was hard to find out. Now someone else have to go deeper and find the real reason inside setToLookAt.